# Mongoose doesn't update my fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an entries, if they are found in my Mongo DB:

```
exports.insert = function(project, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d){
        d.project = project;
        var asset = new Asset(d);

        Asset.findOne({
            project: asset.project,
            ip: asset.ip
        }, function(err, match) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            if (match) {
                console.log('asset found, updating');
                match.mac = 'blablah';
                match.save();
            }
        });
    });

};
```

I also tried to update like this:

```
asset.mac = 'blalah';
match.update(asset);
```

In both cases my fields don't update in the DB. I see no change.

There may be smarter ways to do this but I need to be able to use save or update to do it for future.

NB: Although `findOneAndUpdate` may be the preferred way of doing this, I'm really curious to know why `save()` or `update()` do not work in my case. I would like to know how to use those methods to update my document.

Comment: Why not use `findOneAndUpdate`? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate

Comment: @SlashmanX The reason I wanted to avoid that approach is because I will need to run another set of commands if it is not found (`if (match) { update } else { some other stuff }`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to find one entry and update it, you should use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate):

```
Asset.findOneAndUpdate({
    project: asset.project,
    ip: asset.ip
}, {
    mac: 'blablah'
}, function (err, docThatWasUpdated) {
    ....
})
```

Comment: Can I run other commands in the event that it's not found? IE: "if not found do this stuff instead"

Comment: What do the other commands look like? You can check that `docThatWasUpdated` exists in the callback, and then execute the other commands

Comment: So that does work, but the `docThatWasUpdated` returned is the doc _before_ the update (unchanged values). Looking at the DB directly however I can tell that it does actually updated. I guess this is intended behaviour.

Comment: @Juicy yes, you can pass the option `new: true` to return the updated doc after the changes